# Replace window or document objects with Javascript object

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to replace "window" or "document" objects? What I basically want is to provide some kind of JavaScript Proxy, I want to prevent user from getting "SOME" (only some! this is important) DOM element's on the page. By "user" I mean any third patty script.

I can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")
//NodeList[129]
document.getElementsByTagName = function(){}
//function (){}
document.getElementsByTagName("a")
//undefined
```

But what I can do about `document.all` how can I replace DOM object field to make it return only "SOME" of the DOM elements?

**UPD**: If there is a way to replace 'document' object with some JavaScript object this would be much more better

**UPD2**: I don't care if your method won't work on 'older' browsers. So i'm good with any solution that works on "A" graders

**UPD3**: I know that 100% security doesn't exist in JavaScript, I don't want to prevent hackers from "HACKING", I know it's not possible, I want to prevent developers that write "plugin" for my "home made" framework, to do stupid things..

**UPD4**: ok, I can't replace Document nor Window, but can I at least replace all "fields" or "functions" that repsonsoble for returning "DOM" elements? like "document.getElementById" or "document.all" ?

**UPD5**: User `@pebbl` suggested something that 'close' to the thing I want

```
function a(window, document){
   /// in here window and document should be numerics
   alert(window);
   alert(document);
}

a(123,456);
```

but his solution have one big problem http://jsfiddle.net/kRLax/

**UPD6-7**: This is the 'perfect' one (at least for me)

http://jsfiddle.net/kRLax/12/

```
function Fx(){return function(){}}
function SafeThis(that){ 
    if (that == window) {
        return fakeWindow;
    } else if (that = document) {
        return fakeDocument;                    
    } else {
        return that;
    }
}
var fakeDocument = {
    write: function(a){ document.write(a) }
}
var fakeWindow = {
    document: fakeDocument
}

var moduleA = function(Function, window, document, eval){
    document.write(window + "<br>");
    var f = new Function("return this");
    document.write(f() + "<br>");
    var win = (function(){return this;})();
    document.write(win + "<br>");
    var e = eval("this"); 
    document.write(e + "<br>");
    document.write(this + "<br>");
    document.write(window + "<br>");
    document.write(document + "<br>");
    this.a = 1;
    document.write(JSON.stringify(this));
};

var moduleA_Fx = '!' + 
    moduleA.toString().replace(/\bthis\b/g,"SafeThis(this)") + 
    '(Fx,fakeWindow,fakeDocument,Fx)';

document.write(moduleA_Fx + "<br><br>");

eval(moduleA_Fx);
​
```

Comment: you can't replace "document" or "window", because that'd break the rest of javascript. you could try to override invidual methods.

Comment: well, I'm ok with breaking "the rest" of JavaScript. I'm perfectly aware what i'm doing. So I'm asking is there a way to replace them? (I know that I'd better not do so)

Comment: @Ai_boy If your motivation is to be able to safely embed third-parts scripts in your page, check out [caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/).

Comment: I don't think it lets you.  I just tried setting `window.document` to 5, but it just no-ops and doesn't change the value of the document object.  At least on Chrome.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well I know that 100% security doesn't exist in JavaScript, I don't want to prevent hackers from "HACKING", I know it's not possible, I want to prevent developers that write "plugin" for my "home made" framework, to do stupid things..

Comment: Check out [google_caja]( http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) which is a way off  sandboxing third party apps in the browser

Comment: @Bruno I already looking into that, but I'm not sure yet is it the thing a want or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, but you would have to eval the external script within your function's scope:

```
function a(window, document){
  /// in here window and document should be numerics
  alert(window);
  alert(document);
}

a(123,456);
```

Or if you had a server-side proxy you could rewrite their code with a wrappered anon function that then called in your proxy document and window object.

```
;(function(window, document){

  /// the unknown external code here.

})(windowProxy, documentProxy);
```

There would still be ways around this however, as they might be able to use the following depending on the JS environment:

```
var win = (function(){return this;})();
```

You may also have to include the other collections to make sure they are not accessible:

```
;(function(window, document, all, images, ...){ ... }
```

But, they would also be able to access the original `document` through any dom elements you allowed them access to as well...

#### With regards to UPD6

Just in case it's useful you may also want to plug the following holes:

- setTimeout
- setInterval

Both the above can be used to evaluate code.

```
setTimeout('(function(){alert('+'th'+'is'+');})()');
```

Plus as you are exposing `document.write` this would also be feasible:

```
document.write(
  '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,ERROR" '+
     'onerror="alert(th'+'is.ownerDocument);" />'
);
```

And you should block access to `SafeThis` and rewrite any mention of it in the target code, otherwise it can be overriden:

```
SafeThis = function(that){return that;}
```

Other than that though it seems quite secure. I'm sure there will be other ways round it—if you try hard enough—but it really depends on how determined you think your possible attackers might be ;)

Comment: Cool idea.. if no one give me a better answer I guess I will stick with this solution (there is one broblem with your solution) http://jsfiddle.net/kRLax/

Comment: @Ai_boy yeah that was my point with `var win = (function(){return this;})();` although you may have missed that I edited that in ;) There is also a hole with regard to `Element.document` or `Element.ownerDocument`. However if you made proper `getElementBy` proxies you could theorhetically give them Element proxies as well... but that might be taking it too far :)

Comment: well, anyway you have a good solution (at least for me), I just wait a little to see if there anyone give me a better suggestion..

Comment: @Ai_boy sure thing, no worries -- I'd be interested to see if anything else crops up :) CAJA looks pretty interesting -- mentioned by Šime Vidas -- although rather involved.

Comment: @Ai_boy nice :) just a few points to expand upon, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Tnx a lot, tottaly forgot about "setTimeout" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only reassign writable properties, so `document` and `window` are off the table.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I didn't know that. What is `window` a property of?

Comment: It's a property of the global object, just like `document` is. So, the global object contains a `"window"` property which refers to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

The `"document"` global property is non-writable, and non-configurable, so no, you cannot.

```
// try this in global code
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( this, 'document' ).writable // false
```