# Stop window.location execution in global context

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to stop execution of window.location as in below when a page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Bid closed ');
window.location = '/index.html';
</script>
```

I'm able to bypass `alert` message by replacing `alert` function during `document_start` in the manifest.json. But unable to stop window.location from executing.

Comment: is alert based on condition ?

Comment: Of course not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer looks to me like that of a Math puzzle.

In the injected script I've just placed this code and it seems to work:

```
window.alert =
                function (msg)
                    {
                       throw Error('hello');
                    }
```

This exception is causing the browser to skip the next statement `window.location=`

Comment: For this to be the answer to the question please be specific in the question that you are wanting to stop the execution of that *exact* code. Currently the question reads as how to stop execution of setting `window.location` generally. Without knowing that you are wanting to stop that *exact* code, this does not appear to really answer the question.

Comment: @Makyen this is the solution of what I've asked. I've tested with the code I've asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

`window` object is not writable, so you cannot change `document` and `window` objects 
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518347/replace-window-or-document-objects-with-javascript-object) for more info